# Decorating radio buttons in Zend Form

Tags: zend-form

I have a list of radio buttons, which came from the DB. I want to put each of them into a seperate "td". What I did is:

```
foreach ($notificationTypes as $key => $value) {
            $radios->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
            $radios->removeDecorator('HtmlTag');
                $radios->addMultiOption($value, $value . "_" . $i);

        }
$radios->setDecorators($this->elementDecorators);
        $this->addElement($radios);
```

And this is my decorator:

```
abstract class Myprj_Form_Abstract extends Zend_Form {

    protected  $elementDecorators = array(
    'ViewHelper',
        'Errors',
        array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td', 'class' => 'right_columns')),
        array('Label', array('tag' => 'td')),
        array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr')),
    );
}
```

BUT, what I got is, all the radio buttons located into one td. I know I can do it into the View, but I want to do them into the Form. Is anyone know how to do that?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 3):

I've found the answer, so I'm gonna share it....

I just needed to add

```
$radios->setSeperator('</td></tr><tr><td>');
```

Easy, na?

cheers,